# insertLogical in Optaplanner VRP with tank volumes using Constraint Streams

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to convert a simple VRP project using drl to constraint streams, and I'm not sure how to replicate the functionality of "insertLogical".

The "demand" for each delivery is determined by the number of days from the previous delivery. (The demand is for liquid in tanks being consumed at a known rate.) In drl I'd pair the deliveries and insertLogical, and also insertLogical for the firstDelivery based on the current state.

Without insertLogical, I'm joining deliveries and using a groupBy for paired deliveries, but I can't see how to do an "Outer Join" to include the first delivery.

I also tried creating a continuous planning style "pre-schedule" delivery and then omitting those from the "planning value range". Which would mean the pairs would always exist, but I have a kludgy mess for preventing a Customer from using a pre-schedule vehicle.

So, is there a way to "insertLogical" or to do an outer join in constraint streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and no.

You could build a constraint collector; see `UniConstraintCollector` interface or its bi/tri/... variants. This allows you to implement any custom logic in your groups.

Or you could create a [shadow variable](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/shadow-variable/shadow-variable.html#shadowVariableIntroduction) that would keep track of the first delivery. (In fact, with the new [planning list variable](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/shadow-variable/shadow-variable.html#listVariableShadowVariables), that may be even easier.)

Comment: Would a custom constraintCollector allow me to combine two source lists into a single Tuple stream?

Comment: Constraint Collector is a function from anything to anything, so yes. :-) The question is how to do that incrementally, as in fast. Creating two lists and then combining them will not be fast, assuming all of those operations have to be redone every time any input changes.

Comment: Is there an example or documentation for how to write a constraint collector to concatenate two streams?

Comment: No. The ConstraintCollectors class has plenty of constraint collector implementations you can learn from about incremental calculation, but nothing like this.